# What is the difference between variable === constant & constant === variable

Tags: javascript

I have this following snippet which work as expected. where `x` is a variable

```
var myVariable = (x === 'A' || x=== 'B') ? 'sui' : 'pai';
```

But closure compiler is converting it to

```
var myVariable = ('A' === x || 'B'=== x) ? 'sui' : 'pai';
```

and this is also working.Can you please tell me how the second snippet is better than the first one. Thank you.

Comment: See [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). But in my opinion it is much better to use a linter to catch mistakes like these.

Comment: @str thanks. The link is really helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Human programmers [sometimes do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) to ensure that they don't mix up an `=` assignment operator with an equality `==` operator.

If you use `constant = variable` by mistake instead of `constant == variable` the compiler or interpreter will produce a warning or error.  Chrome, for example, does this:

```
> 'A' = x
VM207:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I'm not sure why a transpiler would bother, since if it's clever enough to be able to swap the arguments to prevent the run-time error it ought to also be clever enough to produce the same warning at transpile time.